# Can't get spark to start

Tags: apache-spark, cmd, command

I have successfully installed and run apache spark in the past on my machine. Today I returned to it and tried to run it using : bin/spark-shell in the spark directory (bin file exists in this dir) but I am getting:

```
bin is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It s running on windows 10 cmd shell, in case this is helpful. What could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAVA_HOME was outdated... I had updated java without updating the path! That was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I belive we need more info, to be able to answr your question.

Using './' specifies a path, starting in the root of your working directory. (Bash or powershell)

1. Are you running this in the cmd shell/powershell/bash shell?
2. What directory are you working in, when trying to execute your command?
3. Is there a bin folder in your current directory? (LS command or dir command)

Comment: yes there is a bin folder. I m in the spark directory and I am using cmd shell!

Comment: Did you try executing the command  from the full path? ex. C:\bin\spark-shell? Im pretty sure that ./ is not the right syntax, for a cmd-shell. Instead try bin/spark-shell.

Comment: I have tried this too but: The system cannot find the path specified.. and I  am very sure I am giving the right path and there is a bin folder that contains spark-shell file. (tried with spark-shell.cmd too)

Comment: Try this: find the cmd file via windows explorer, SHIFT+Right MB click, and chose "copy as path". Paste the path into cmd-Shell and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Check version of java installed and location where environment variable JAVA_HOME is pointing to.

In my case JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 (this is old version)

The cause of this issue was that I installed a new version of JDK and removed the previous installation but JAVA_HOME was pointing to the old environment which was missing.